# Get real calendar days between two dates

Tags: go

I'm trying to get amount of days between two dates in Go but as I'm getting the difference in time (hours) and then divided by the amount of time per day, I have an issue.

**Problem:** if dates are different (7 of May and 8 of May) but the time between then is lower than 24h, my code counts as there are no days in between.

**What I want:** count real days in between.

```
// Days
firstDay := firstDate.Unix()
lastDay := lastDate.Unix()
fmt.Println("firstDay: ", firstDay)
fmt.Println("lastDay: ", lastDay)

if firstDay > lastDay {
        fmt.Println("IS TO SMALL")
    return
}

// businessDays = 
businessDays := (lastDay - firstDay) / 86400
fmt.Println("businessDays: ", businessDays)
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: The reason your code does that is because you are dividing by days, so by 24 hour increments. Try dividing by the smallest unit you want measured, i.e. a minute or a second, and your result should change.

Comment: Do you need to start from unix timestamps? If you already have the exact times, why not compare the days directly?

Comment: I was doing it this way because if I use something like .Day() it won't work nicely if I have different months/years etc.
I could change the time to 0 AM in both dates but I don't know a clean way of doing this.

Comment: It also depends on what you mean by "days" - dividing by 24-hour periods is unlikely to be what you want, because it doesn't take into account daylight savings, leap seconds, etc. This is why there is no `Duration` constant in Go larger than `Hour` - longer durations are harder to work with using basic math and require consideration of calendars and time zones.

Comment: @Trody: There's no such thing as an official "day length", so you're always going to have to account for these things.

Comment: Use time.Year and time.YearDay and a bit of (ugly) leap year logic.

Comment: Aside: use Time.After or Time.Before to compare time values. This considers the monotonic parts of the values.

Answer (score 9):

1. Use [`Duration.Hours()`](https://godoc.org/time#Duration.Hours) to get hours
2. Use [`math.Ceil()`](https://godoc.org/math#Ceil) to find calendar days
3. Use [`Time.Truncate()`](https://godoc.org/time#Time.Truncate) to truncate hour and minute, only save day

The source code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    d1, err := time.Parse("200601021504", "201801020001")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    d2, err := time.Parse("200601021504", "201801020002")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    newD1 := d1.Truncate(time.Hour * 24)
    newD2 := d2.Truncate(time.Hour * 24)

    fmt.Printf("days: %v\n", math.Ceil(newD2.Sub(newD1).Hours()/24))

}
```

Comment: This may be off by one when the date range straddles a DST change.

Comment: Isn't this the same? If I have 11:59PM 7 May, and 00:01AM 8 May it should count 1 day even I only have a couple of minutes in between. But at the same time it should return 0 if I'm on the same date and small difference.

Comment: If I remove the time out of the date and leave 00:00 then my original code works flawlessly in UTC. I thought this on the bigging by getting the .Date() and then getting the value with time.date but that looks a bit slow to me. Right? https://play.golang.org/p/GELyEMAmSaf

Comment: @Trody I change the source code. After change code, the days calculate is correct.

Answer (score 3):

There are many things to worry about. For example, due to daylight saving time (DST), not all days are 24 hours. What if the times are in different time zones? And so on.

Here's a solution that addresses these issues.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

// CalendarDays returns the calendar difference between times (t2 - t1) as days.
func CalendarDays(t2, t1 time.Time) int {
    y, m, d := t2.Date()
    u2 := time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    y, m, d = t1.In(t2.Location()).Date()
    u1 := time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
    days := u2.Sub(u1) / (24 * time.Hour)
    return int(days)
}

func main() {
    first := time.Now().Round(0)
    end := first.Add(48 * time.Hour)
    for last := first; last.Before(end); last = last.Add(6 * time.Hour) {
        fmt.Println("Days:", CalendarDays(last, first), "Last:", last, "First:", first)
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/wKwQzgfKa8f

Output:

```
Days: 0 Last: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 0 Last: 2018-02-05 23:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 1 Last: 2018-02-06 05:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 1 Last: 2018-02-06 11:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 1 Last: 2018-02-06 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 1 Last: 2018-02-06 23:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 2 Last: 2018-02-07 05:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
Days: 2 Last: 2018-02-07 11:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST First: 2018-02-05 17:38:15.623292254 -0500 EST
```

Answer (score 1):

As performance is now an issue (which I doubt), I wrote some benchmarks with approaches I come around:

```
func TrimToDate(t time.Time) time.Time {
    y, m, d := t.Date()
    return time.Date(y, m, d, 0, 0, 0, 0, time.UTC)
}

func CountTrim(t1, t2 time.Time) int {
    return int((t2.Unix() - TrimToDate(t1.Unix())) / 86400)
}

func CountUnixAdd(t1, t2 time.Time) int {
    Days := (t1.Unix() - t2.Unix()) / 86400

    if t1.Add(time.Duration(Days)*24*time.Hour).Day() != t2.Day() {
        Days++
    }

    return int(Days)
}

func CountDivMul(t1, t2 time.Time) int {
    d1 := t1.Unix() / 86400 * 86400
    return int((t2.Unix() - d1) / 86400)
}
```

Where `CountTrim` use the `time.Time.Date` method to trim the hours and minutes and so on. Note that only once `TrimToDate` needs to be called, as the remaining would be discarded by the integer division.

`CountUnixAdd` is a plain and simple way: Test if it is the same date, if not, adds one.

`CountDivMul` is almost the same idea of trimming to day, but use a more hack-y way: using integer division to get rid of the remainnings and then multiply back.

The benchmark result on my laptop:

```
goos: windows
goarch: amd64
pkg: test/stackoverflow/dateprb
BenchmarkCountTrim-8            20000000                62.7 ns/op
BenchmarkCountDivMul-8          1000000000               2.12 ns/op
BenchmarkCountUnixAdd-8         20000000                77.8 ns/op
PASS
ok      test/stackoverflow/dateprb      5.367s
```

Unsurprisingly, the hack-y way is way faster than the other while the two usual way is almost the same.

Full code (of benchmark and of functions) [here](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/leafbebop/5e6zxL)